# get the target path from a nethood link

Tags: vbscript, hyperlink, shortcut, filepath, absolute-path

Let's say I have a nethood link to a folder with the name "BLABLA" and the target path is "\\servername\temp"

how do I get the string for the target path?
I tried:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Const NET_HOOD = &H13&
Set oShApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
sNetHood = oShApp.NameSpace(NET_HOOD).Self.Path
Set oShortCut = oShell.CreateShortcut(sNetHood & "\" & "BLABLA" & ".lnk")

MsgBox "> " & oShortCut.TargetPath
```

It does everything, even creates a oShortCut object without any errors.
But, it does not return

```
oShortCut.TargetPath
```

what am I doing wrong?

I'd like it to return this: "\\servername\temp\BLABLA"
Thanks in advance for any advice!

I've created the shortcut under win 7 with right click in Computer view of the explorer and then > Add a network location > Next ... etc. It creates a Folder representing a shortcut in NetHood to the path on the server ... it's like a mapped share but not really it.

Comment: btw. the read only methods oShortCut.FullName works like a charm ... returning the utterly useless relative path to the link

Comment: Give a look at that one on SO esp. that second answer with code for Win32_LogicalDisk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336685/mapping-a-network-drive-and-checking-for-its-existence-in-vbscript

Comment: returns only the mapped shares ... but not the folder shortcuts' target paths

Answer (score -1):

thx for the input ... after years of reading myself into the matter and then checking google once more i found a c# code which i wrote into vbs and then simplified only to see that all i had to change in the end was to add this:

```
.GetLink
```

so the solution to my problem is:

```
Const NET_HOOD = &H13&
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oFolder = oShell.NameSpace(NET_HOOD)

For Each oFile In oFolder.Items
    MsgBox oFile.GetLink.Path
Next
```