# VBScript file copy FileExists return false mounted drive drive

Tags: vbscript, installshield, file-copying, mounted-volumes

I am under the context of a script executed within an installation package MSI created with InstallShield. I execute the below script:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
User = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )
MsgBox "User: " & User

' The parameters are received through MSI parameters
' msiexec /I MyMSI_x64.msi configFileSrc="Z:\MyFolder\FileToCopy.txt" configFolderDst="c:\temp\"

' Testing parameters
Dim configFileSrc, configFolderDst
configFileSrc = "Z:\MyFolder\FileToCopy.txt"
configFolderDst = "c:\temp\"

' **********************************************************************
' Copy file to destination folder
' **********************************************************************
if(configFileSrc <> "") Then
    call copyFile(configFileSrc, configFolderDst)
End if

' **********************************************************************
' Function to copy file
' **********************************************************************
Sub CopyFile(SourceFile, DestinationFile)

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If not fso.FileExists(SourceFile) Then
        MsgBox "The file " & SourceFile & " is not found and will therefore not be copied to destination folder.", vbExclamation, "Parameter file not found" 
        Exit Sub
    End If 
 ...
```

The FileExists always return false when executed from a mounted drive. When the script is executed locally (replacing configFileSrc which is actually provided as a parameter), the the script works fine.
I am pretty sure that InstallShield use the Admin local account of the machine which have potentially no permission on the mounted drive but I don't know how to check. I have tried to display the current user strUserName but the box is empty.
Any idea?

Comment: Your problem analysis is probably correct. The reason why you are not seeing the username is because you are setting the variable `User` and not `strUserName`. Using `Option Explicit` would have made this apparent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping a network drive and checking for its existence in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336685/mapping-a-network-drive-and-checking-for-its-existence-in-vbscript)

Comment: Hello Lankymart, thanks. No it does not address my question. In my situation the network share is already mounted and accessing it cause the issue despite a correct path.

Comment: HI  Geert, thanks, dummy mistake. Actually, it invalidated my hypothese. The wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings show the same user than the logged in user which has the relevant privileges to access the network share.

Answer (score 0):

Mapped drives are per user token. Admins have two tokens. So running as admin means it does not have access to mapped drives as a normal user.

Use UNC paths. `\\server\sharename\folder\file.ext`.

Comment: In fact, I am receiving the paths through MSI parameters (I updated the main post). I have no control over what is received :-S